# efficient storage and retrieval of large set of objects in dictionaries/arrays

Tags: ios

I am creating a data source from a user's complete set of photos stored on the device (which may number in the thousands).

For each asset, I need:

- URL
- latitude
- longitude
- timestamp

When the view loads, I will enumerate all of the assets and store these 4 pieces of data for each asset. I am wondering if there are significant differences among the options for arranging all of this data. For example:

1. Create 1 array, with each object in the array containing a dictionary with 4 key-value pairs.

vs.

2. Create 1 array, containing just the URL strings. Create 3 additional dictionaries, 1 mapping each URL string to a latitude, 1 mapping each URL string to a longitude, and 1 mapping each URL string to a timestamp.

vs.

3. Same as #1, but instead of adding dictionaries to the array, add instances of a custom class subclassed from NSObject and containing 4 properties.

Are there significant differences in the time required to create or read from these collections (assuming thousands of objects)? Thanks.

Comment: "Are there significant differences in the time" Try both. Use Instruments. Find out. Don't optimize prematurely; optimize _factually_.

Comment: Choosing the right data structure depends on your needs. What operations  with this information you'll perform?
I agree with @matt 's comment, choose the simplest — variant 1 and measure .

Comment: Maybe you should create a CustomObject with 3 properties url, timestamp, location and store this object in an array.( or 4 if you don`t want to store longitude and  latitude as a point) or you specify a search logic which only loads specific images from the photogallery

Comment: Write the simpliest most clear code you can. If there is a performance problem measure and correct. Quotes: Kent Beck: “Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work”, C. A. R. Hoare: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming."

Comment: I could try both and measure, but I was hoping for some insight into *why* one approach would likely be preferable a priori. But still, thank you for pointing out the common wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the simplest that would save you time and would have a very low overhead would be to create a class that holds the four properties you want to create and put them in a dictionary. Making your own object to hold these pieces of information rather than rigging together a couple arrays or dictionaries will allow for more flexibility in the future.

As you enumerate through the photos, set the objects in the dictionary with the timestamp as the key (or whatever unique property you want). You can sort the keys in `O(n*(log n))` and access entries in `O(1)` time. Then you have a sorted list of all images, it's quick, scalable, and you can easily add more properties in the future.

Comment: Thanks. This is another option I had considered, which I figured was pretty similar to #1. I edited my question to reflect that. I did wonder if creating an instance of a simple object like this would incur more overhead than creating an instance of NSMutableDictionary. What do you mean by put them in a dictionary? Would you not just make each of the 4 pieces of data a public property?

Comment: All four properties would be public, but by using a dictionary you have constant time access if you have the key. Since `NSDictionary` uses an array of `allKeys` you also have the same time advantages of using an `NSArray`. In reality, unless you're planning on dealing with 1m+ photos, you're not going to notice a significant advantage in time complexity with one option over another. I advocate `NSDictionary` for the programming advantages.